# Search and login overlap in the new topbar

Tags: support, bug, status-declined, top-bar, internet-explorer-8

When I tried StackOverflow.com in IE 8, this is what happened to me.

[image: sign up log search]

The log in and search text box overlap, but when using Chrome, it looks fine
So I wonder why this is happening? Is it a coding bug that results to crossbrowser issues?

Comment: "*Internet Explorer 8 is no longer officially supported by Stack Exchange. Bugs related to this browser are unlikely to be fixed.*" I'd suggest you update your IE, if possible.

Comment: @3ventic do you have the link for official post regarding IE

Comment: @Bala [this faq](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/56161/152859)

Comment: @Bala that's from [tag:internet-explorer-8] tag wiki